# How do you ensure price recency shown to user in your ecommerce store

Tags: web-applications, e-commerce

What I mean is imagine you are a customer and you add 2 items to your cart at 02:58 pm, while there is a scheduled price change at 03:00 exactly for your products and let say you decide to pay the products at 02:59 and while you are writing your debit/credit card data to the form which takes you 2 minutes, the price has already changed but you weren't aware of that change, because you were writing your data. So how can this problem be avoided? How is it done by the ecommerce giants? Share some knowledge if you have expirience with such cases or an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

1. You decide the price at the time of 'placing the order' not paying for the order.
2. You version the SKUs and whenever anything about a SKU changes (including price), update its version number.
3. You 'decommission' the previous versions of the SKU at a set schedule (eg: daily).

If you are using SKU decommissioning, you should account for orders pending in the system. You can only decommission SKUs when there are no pending orders. Also, your product catalog listing must show only the latest version of a SKU.

This will ensure that an order line item is frozen with a SKU + version number (and hence the price at the time of placing the order). If you want to alert the user to a price change, you can do so, by checking that there are no new versions of the SKUs in the order before the user is allowed to click the pay button. If there are, those price changes could be highlighted to the user and they can decide if they want to proceed with the order or not.

In summary, use the Order to Cash flow as:

1. Create the Order - capture the customer's buying intent (product,
   qty etc.,)
2. Create the Invoice - apply the pricing. Once invoice
   is created, price on the order is frozen.
3. Pay the Invoice against the Order and record payment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !!! I am gonna try to implement it. In the meantime if someone has other ideas please share them.